# data extraction and its summation using python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a following data representation in an text file called as

data.txt

```
03/05/2016 16:43  502
03/05/2016 16:43  502
03/05/2016 16:44  501
03/05/2016 16:44  504
03/05/2016 16:44  505
03/05/2016 16:44  506
04/05/2016 16:44  501
04/05/2016 16:45  501
04/05/2016 16:45  501
04/05/2016 16:45  52
04/05/2016 17:08  50
05/05/2016 17:08  502
05/05/2016 17:08  503
05/05/2016 17:08  504
05/05/2016 17:09  506
06/05/2016 17:09  507
06/05/2016 17:09  507
07/05/2016 17:09  508
07/05/2016 17:09  50
08/05/2016 17:10  5
08/05/2016 17:10  504
09/05/2016 17:10  504
09/05/2016 17:10  503
09/05/2016 17:10  503
10/05/2016 17:11  505
10/05/2016 17:11  505
```

I want to perform certain mathematical operation such that i can obtain the end result as

```
03/05/2016   3020
04/05/2016   1605
05/05/2016   2015
06/05/2016   5023
07/05/2016   1014
08/05/2016   558
09/05/2016   5023
10/05/2016   5022
```

the second column is sum of values

where this result is stored in another text file say data1.txt

I want to write this code in python 2.7

How can i achieve this....

Comment: Could you elaborate on "certain mathematical operation"?

Comment: i want to sum the result in the 3rd column of data.txt

Comment: the resulting output of second column should be sum of 3rd column of data.txt

Comment: Must the output date be sorted?

Comment: If you sum the 3rd column, you will get a single number. If you mean sum grouping by date, then how did you get 502 for 07/05/2016?

Comment: If you know how to read the file in using csv.reader, then you can use collections.Counter to get what you wanted easily

Comment: ya like shown in expected output

Comment: @bereal yes sir i am sorry the sum obtained in expected  output is wrong

Comment: i have just given an example @bereal

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) to sum the values on given date:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('data.txt') as f:
    res = sum((Counter({d: int(c)}) for d, t, c in (line.split() for line in f)), Counter())

with open('data1.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.writelines('{0}\t{1}\n'.format(*x) for x in sorted(res.items()))
```

Output:

```
03/05/2016  3020
04/05/2016  1605
05/05/2016  2015
06/05/2016  1014
07/05/2016  558
08/05/2016  509
09/05/2016  1510
10/05/2016  1010
```

This solution wouldn't require any libraries outside of standard Python installation.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/GhOsT/Desktop/oo.py", line 4, in <module>
    res = sum((Counter({d: int(c)}) for d, t, c in (line.split() for line in f)), Counter())
  File "C:/Users/GhOsT/Desktop/oo.py", line 4, in <genexpr>
    res = sum((Counter({d: int(c)}) for d, t, c in (line.split() for line in f)), Counter())
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack

Comment: @DarrenSam: Did you try with the same input as provided in the question? If not could you please save the example input to a file and try with it? I've tested this with Python 2.7 and for me it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

A pure python solution:

```
import collections

data=collections.defaultdict(int)
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        row=line.split()
        data[row[0]]+=int(row[2])

with open('data1.txt', 'w') as f:
    for key, value in sorted(data.items()):
        f.write(str(key)+" "+str(value)+"\n")
```

Output:

```
$ python a.py 
$ cat data1.txt 
03/05/2016 3020
04/05/2016 1605
05/05/2016 2015
06/05/2016 1014
07/05/2016 558
08/05/2016 509
09/05/2016 1510
10/05/2016 1010
$
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/GhOsT/Desktop/oo.py", line 7, in <module>
    data[row[0]]+=int(row[2])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @DarrenSam it works fine here for version `2.7.6` and the data that you have posted

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
f = open('data.txt')
res = OrderedDict()
for line in f:

    values = line.split(' ')
    if len(values) == 4:
        date = values[0]
        val = values[3]
        if res.get(date):
            res[date] += int(val)
        else:
            res[date] = int(val)

f.close()

f = open('data1.txt', 'w')
for line in res.keys():
    f.write('{} {}\n'.format(line, res[line]))
f.close()
```

Comment: sir can u plz explain this

Comment: if res.get(date):
            res[date] += int(val)
        else:
            res[date] = int(val)

Comment: res.get(date) what does this statement do

Comment: Actual you can replace it with `has_key`. `get` - return value by key from dict but if it doesn't exists it returns None.

Answer (score 0):

#### Setup

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

text = """03/05/2016 16:43  502
03/05/2016 16:43  502
03/05/2016 16:44  501
03/05/2016 16:44  504
03/05/2016 16:44  505
03/05/2016 16:44  506
04/05/2016 16:44  501
04/05/2016 16:45  501
04/05/2016 16:45  501
04/05/2016 16:45  52
04/05/2016 17:08  50
05/05/2016 17:08  502
05/05/2016 17:08  503
05/05/2016 17:08  504
05/05/2016 17:09  506
06/05/2016 17:09  507
06/05/2016 17:09  507
07/05/2016 17:09  508
07/05/2016 17:09  50
08/05/2016 17:10  5
08/05/2016 17:10  504
09/05/2016 17:10  504
09/05/2016 17:10  503
09/05/2016 17:10  503
10/05/2016 17:11  505
10/05/2016 17:11  505"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), delim_whitespace=True,
                 parse_dates=[0], names=['date', 'time', 'value'])
```

#### Looks like

```
         date   time  value
0  2016-03-05  16:43    502
1  2016-03-05  16:43    502
2  2016-03-05  16:44    501
3  2016-03-05  16:44    504
4  2016-03-05  16:44    505
5  2016-03-05  16:44    506
6  2016-04-05  16:44    501
7  2016-04-05  16:45    501
8  2016-04-05  16:45    501
9  2016-04-05  16:45     52
10 2016-04-05  17:08     50
11 2016-05-05  17:08    502
12 2016-05-05  17:08    503
13 2016-05-05  17:08    504
14 2016-05-05  17:09    506
15 2016-06-05  17:09    507
16 2016-06-05  17:09    507
17 2016-07-05  17:09    508
18 2016-07-05  17:09     50
19 2016-08-05  17:10      5
20 2016-08-05  17:10    504
21 2016-09-05  17:10    504
22 2016-09-05  17:10    503
23 2016-09-05  17:10    503
24 2016-10-05  17:11    505
25 2016-10-05  17:11    505
```

#### Solution

```
df.groupby('date').sum()
```

Comment: sir i want to add the result in the 3rd column